# How threads works in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tello-drone

I'm trying to create app for controlling djitello basing on some tutorials and i want to create possibility to click on some gui tabs and during that control drone by keyboard.
So i  thought about using threads but i can't write it. Right now when i use my app it freezes after clicking button which activates method for keyboard control. Can someone explain what am i doing wrong?

This is class for keyboardControl:

```
from Modules.KeyPressModule import GetKeyPressed as keyPressed
from time import sleep
import logging

class KeyboardControlService():
    def __init__(self,passedTello):
        self.tello = passedTello
        self.startControl = False

    def Initialize(self,ui):
        self.ui = ui

    def GetKeyboardInput(self):
        lr,fb,ud,yv = 0,0,0,0
        speed = 30

        if(keyPressed("left")): lr = speed
        elif (keyPressed("right")): lr = -speed

        if(keyPressed("up")): fb = speed
        elif (keyPressed("down")): fb = -speed

        if(keyPressed("w")): ud = speed
        elif (keyPressed("s")): ud = -speed

        if(keyPressed("a")): yv = speed
        elif (keyPressed("d")): yv = -speed

        if(keyPressed("q")): self.tello.land()
        elif (keyPressed("e")): self.tello.takeoff()


        return [lr,fb,ud,yv]

    def StartControl(self):
        self.startControl = True
        while self.startControl:
            values = self.GetKeyboardInput()
            print("test")
            #self.tello.send_rc_control(values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3])
            sleep(0.05)
    def EndControl(self):
        self.startControl = False
```

This class is for button clicking response:

```
from djitellopy import Tello
from threading import Thread
from Services.KeyboardControlService import KeyboardControlService as keyboardControlService

class TelloService():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tello = Tello()
        self.keyboardControlService = keyboardControlService(self.tello)

    def UseKeyboardControl(self,UseIt,UI):
        if(UseIt == True):
            self.keyboardControlService.Initialize(UI)
            self.keyboardThread = Thread(target=self.keyboardControlService.StartControl(), daemon=True)
            self.keyboardThread.start()
        else:
            self.keyboardControlService.EndControl()
            self.keyboardThread.join()
```

Comment: it would help if you removed the unnecessary parts from your code, and only keep the one that's causing an issue

Comment: I wanted to show whole two classes, main trouble in my opinion is in creating thread or maybe getting keyboard input. 
Thread is created in UseKeyboardControl method and keyboard input is used in StartControl method

Comment: yeah, you have to pass a function, not call the function. That means you have to remove the parenthesis `()` after `StartControl`

Comment: oh okay this change a lot, but i'm not sure how i can write function without self and still having reference to tello (drone) without that i can't move him

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is now? Is the multithreading resolved?

Comment: I'm still not sure if im doing it right. I changed  code a little bit. KeyboardControlService now  inherits threading which looks like this 
"class KeyboardControlService(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,passedTello):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)"

apart from the fact that there is a long delay in reading the keys, I can't stop the thread. I used 
thread.join() but after that whole app freezes and that's it

Comment: sorry, but I can't help you anymore with this. To read more on threading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score -1):

Okey i resolved it
The trouble was here :

```
self.keyboardThread = Thread(target=self.keyboardControlService.StartControl(), daemon=True)
```

I passed function not the object